# Copy over a value from one list to another object which can be uniquely identified by the maps key efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I have a map of type `Map<Long, Long>`. The key represents the unique id of an `Employee`. The value represents the amount of time he has worked. I also have a `List<ProjectEmployee>`. A `ProjectEmployee` is defined the following way:

```
public class ProjectEmployee {

  private Employee employee;
  private Project project;
  private Long workTime;
}
```

Theres always only one `ProjectEmployee` per employee. So a `ProjectEmployee` can be uniquely identified by its employee.

I now want to copy the value saved in the map over to the `workTime` of the `ProjectEmployee` which employees id is equal to the maps key. So for example, if the map has a pair `10=>20`, I would like to find the `ProjectEmployee` whos employee has the id `10` and set the `workTime` field of that `ProjectEmployee` to 20.

I would like to know whether theres a way to do this in less than O(n^2). The naive approach im thinking of, is to iterate over the entire map and inside the loop, iterate over all `ProjectEmployees` till I find the one im searching for the current map pair and then copy over the field.

Assume that every employee id key inside `Map<Long, Long>`, has exactly one `ProjectEmployee` it can be mapped to in the given list.

Comment: Couldn't you make a Map from EmployeeID->EmployeeProject in O(N) time, then do the updates in O(N) time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
projectEmployees.forEach(pe -> pe.setWorkTime(map.get(pe.getEmployee().getId())));
```

Possibly with a check, map.containsKey.

Of course if the map is merely a tiny fraction of project employees, you'll
need a mapping of IDs to project employees.

Comment: Ye, i think thats the best solution. The other posted solution also works in O(n), but i guess yours has a better constant factor, because you only loop through one loop instead of two like in the other solution.

Comment: It depends, the other solution might fit problems of other readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in O(n) time pretty easily, with O(n) auxiliary space: start by building a `Map<Long, ProjectEmployee>` out of your list, where the key is the `ProjectEmployee` object's `employee`'s ID number. Then in the second loop, use the map to get `ProjectEmployee` objects by ID in O(1) time each.

It could look something like this:

```java
// stage 1: build a map
Map<Long, ProjectEmployee> byId = new HashMap<>();
for(ProjectEmployee p : employeeList) {
    byId.put(p.employee.id, p);
}

// stage 2: do the updates
for(Map.Entry<Long, Long> e : workTimeMap.entrySet()) {
    ProjectEmployee p = byId.get(e.getKey());
    p.workTime = e.getValue();
}
```

Depending on what else you need the `ProjectEmployee` objects for, it may make more sense to store them in a map in the first place, instead of a list.